# Calling IAB across multiple activities

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I have an app that has implemented In App Billing for a premium version of my app.  On startup, I check if the user has purchased the product using `IabHelper`.  When I load up my next activity, I need to check for the purchase again to decide whether or not to show certain menu content.  I do not want to store the result of the call at startup in preferences or local db for security reasons and understand the Play information is cached anyway.  Is my best option in the second activity to create a new instance of `IabHelper` and call `startSetup()` again then `queryInventoryAsync()`?  Trouble with this is, as the call is asynchronous, I'm not sure when the response will return in order to update the UI menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I'm currently doing as well. I use the async callback to update a previously held menu object to show/hide a purchase option which in reality is never seen the speed of the returned call.

To speed up the process if you call `queryInventoryAsync(false, mGotInventoryListener);` (note the false flag) then you will only use a local cached inventory which is far quicker to respond.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was going to do, just wondered if there was a delay in the response. Plus every activity calling IabHelper has a lot of duplicated code which I did think about turning into a singleton?

Comment: I don't like the duplication either but with the callbacks it would get very messy as a singleton as you would need at least some of those callbacks to point to the current activity.  You also can't guarantee your app's entry point so initalizing in the main activity won't work.